# Handle & symbol in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have an oracle stored procedure which accepts varchar2 input parameter. My problem is that some of the input parameter contains "&" or "<" sign. Since these are the special character Oracle ignores it.

Since this is stored procedure i can not do SET DEFINE OFF as it is called by some system.

Can you please help on this as i want to store data with this special character like "A & M Solution" or "hemil mistry"

Any help on this

Answer (score 1):

You need to set DEFINE OFF in the caller, not in the procedure.
For example:

```
create or replace procedure doSomething(str in varchar2) is
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(str);
end;
```

If I call this procedure from SQLPlus, I get:

```
SQL> exec doSomething('&&&');
&&&

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec doSomething('&aa');
Enter value for aa: XXX
XXX

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

After setting DEFINE OFF, I have:

```
SQL> set define off
SQL> exec doSomething('&aa');
&aa

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table s (str varchar2(4000));
create or replace procedure storestr(str in varchar2) is
begin
insert into s values(str);
commit;
end;
/
exec storestr('&&&');
exec storestr('&&<');
select * from s;
```

Everything works fine.
What is your problem? Maybe please post what your procedure is going to do with data containing special characters.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass specials characters as input parameters you should use function

> chr()

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions019.htm

example:

```
set serveroutput on size 3000

create or replace procedure p_accept_special_char(ip_str in varchar2) is
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(ip_str);
end;
/
exec p_accept_special_char(chr(38)||chr(62)||chr(60))
/
```

output:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on size 3000
SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure p_accept_special_char(ip_str in varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3      dbms_output.put_line(ip_str);
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_accept_special_char(chr(38)||chr(62)||chr(60))
&><

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```